# Compute CRC according to CCITT polynome (x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1)

Tags: java, c#, checksum, crc

I have a checksum method that computes the CRC to CCIT polynome written in C#. Now I have to write the same method in java, but I don't know how to write the method in java.

```
private int ComputeChecksum(byte[] buf, int StartIdx, int EndIdx)
    {
        int CRC = 0xFFFF;

        for (int i = StartIdx; i < EndIdx; i++)
        {
            int ch = buf[i];          /* Process one byte                  */

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                int xo = (CRC ^ ch) & 0x0001;

                CRC >>= 1;
                ch  >>= 1;

                if (xo == 1)
                    CRC ^= 0x8408;      /* Toggle bits / set incoming bit    */
            }
        }

        return CRC ^ 0xFFFF;        // 1's complement
    }
```

Comment: You could change all of the comments to "// ...", and start with your existing c# code, making changes as needed.

Comment: Yess, i try this code in Java but it gives a totally wrong checksum. Could you help me figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Try using `char[] buf` instead of `byte [] buf` .

Comment: how should i write the code in java, that calculates the checksum?

Comment: Other than changing byte to char, it will probably work as is.